# Why is WP displaying a shortcode to end users upon profile submission?

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have a profile form that logged-in users can fill in. When the form is submitted what should happen, as far as I'm aware, is the profile should get redisplayed along with a message to confirm to the user that their contact information has been submitted.

What is actually happening is that the user is shown the page with just the shortcode displayed - [civicrm component=”profile” mode=”edit” gid=”28″] - and no confirmation message.

The URL is https://example.com/application-form/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fprofile%2Fview&reset=1&id=102&gid=28

Nothing in the browser console.

WP: 5.5.3, Civi: 5.31.1.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with using profiles on Wordpress sites, where the profile is presented via a shortcode, is that when the form is submitted the user does not get presented with the default text statement alluded to in the help message about their contact information having been submitted, but is instead just presented with the page again. Worse than this, the profile isn't shown to the user, but they see the shortcode in all its ugly unhelpfulness.

The workaround that I've implemented is to ensure in the profile settings that a redirect URL is set, pointing to a nice thank-you page.